# Are quarks and atoms an observable physical manifestation of the Dvar Havaya that is keeping the universe in existence?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, science, creation

> המחדש בטובו בכל יום תמיד מעשה בראשית

> In His goodness, He renews the work of creation every day, continuously

As explained by the Baal Shem Tov and cited by the Baal Hatanya in [Book 2, Ch. 1 of the Tanya](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7987/jewish/Chapter-1.htm), the *Dvar Havaya* ("word of God") is constantly keeping the world in existence, without which the world would cease to exist.

Question: Has there been any discussion about the possibility of quarks and atoms being a physical manifestation of this Dvar Havaya that is keeping the universe in existence?

*According to science all matter is essentially energy. Everything is constantly in motion. Electrons in the atom, and deeper down there are quarks, which are all in a constant frenetic state of motion.*

*What is unique about quarks and atoms is that you can see physically how even items that you would think are dead, like stones, are really made up of molecules or particles or whatever you want to call it that is essentially energy. Everything is constantly being energized by some Force. Nothing is dead matter.*

*Everything is essentially made up of a few of the same particles that are always in motion, and it's really all 99% empty space.*

---

Comment: What do you mean by "Dvar Havaya"?

Comment: @Deuteronomy the word of God that causes: דבכל רגע השי"ת ממציא כל הנמצאים ממש יש מאין

Comment: Everything is a manifestation of the Word of G-d that sustains existence. What exactly is unique about quarks and atoms?

Comment: There was an excellent documentary produced around 1997 called, "Stephen Hawking's Universe" which discussed this concept without explicitly referencing biblical language. As I recall, Hawking said that the entire universe appears to wink in and out of existence constantly, but across infinite points. Think in the context of a pointillist painting. Our perception is of the whole set of points and therefore, we do not perceive the moment of non-existence. Hawking noted that "something outside of existence" appears to force the continuation of existence constantly.

Comment: @YaacovDeane can you find out what exact theory/philosophy this is, perhaps by asking on SA Physics?

Comment: Why the addition of "word"? God Himself is the one that is מחדש בטובו בכל יום תמיד מעשה בראשית (in His goodness renews the work of creation every day continuously). What is your basis for saying that it is the word of God (i.e. a creation) that sustains creation, rather than the Creator?

Comment: I'm not expert in cosmology or theology, but it seems quite trivial to prove that whatever science thinks is the most likely way the world works is the best guess we have for the "physical manifestation" of how God is running it.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I assume that's based on לעולם ה' דברך נצב בשמים as explained in Tanya: https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7987/jewish/Chapter-1.htm

Comment: @shmosel i think so, yes, thank you

Comment: @DoubleAA i agree with you. I'm not trying to prove anything. I'm looking to "corroborate" or "reinforce".

Comment: @shmosel what is unique about quirks and atoms is that you can see physically how even items that you would think are dead, like Stones, are really made up of molecules or particles or whatever you want to call it that is essentially energy. everything is constantly being energized by some Force. Nothing is dead matter.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't believe your assertion that it is trivial to look into nature to find God. (Someone please help me here,) There are passages in the tanach and other places where it talks about finding God through nature, etc.

Comment: The lubavitcher Rebbe said that Hashem didn't need to make the world require constant recreation, but He did so in His _goodness_ (often overlooked word in that prayer). Tanya says that Hashem isnt too lofty for us, He is beyond lofty completely. So whether the universe is energised by energy or is just matter, it doesn't make a difference to Him so it is hard to understand, without a mesora, what the way He did do it means or tells us about Him. Hard, not impossible and there are lots of fun things to spot and learn, as you've pointed out, hatzlacha

Comment: Your observation is valid, which is that fundamentally, "There is nothing there." I.e. matter does not by default have a continuous existence which stretches indefinitely into the past and the future, hence existence is ephemeral. It is not *muchach* from quantum physics exactly how ephemeral it is, however.

Comment: @RabbiKaii The concept of continuous creation is the plain meaning of the words of the Yotzer prayer said before reciting Shema. המחדש בטובו בכל יום תמיד מעשה בראשית. This is an explicit teaching from the Ba'al Shem Tov. טובו is a reference to G-d's name אהוה (gematria Tov, 17) and which is the roshei teivot of (את-השמים ואת-הארץ). That He, His name, His vitality and His causations are one. Regarding the statement from Hawking, it is part of String Theory. If you are interested in the subject, read the many books from Brian Greene. https://www.briangreene.org/books-and-writings/

Comment: @Deuteronomy My preceding comment is the answer to your question above concerning His words. "His words" are His causations and unlike all of His creations, where speech is separate from their perspective, nothing is separate in regard to G-d.

Comment: How are quarks not dead? The idea that Hashem is constantly keeping the world going (not just found in Chabad) was said many centuries before quantum physics and refers to spiritual, metaphysical realities that should be above our ability to observe naturally.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I have read them but I've never seen the idea you mentioned from the documentary. I will ask on Physics sa

Comment: @N.T. Try looking at Mishneh Torah, Hilchot Yesodei HaTorah, Chapter 1, in particular laws 1-7. All of creation is an expression of and from G-d. See also Devarim 4:39, Job 19:26 and Job 35:5. The primary means for us to relate and connect with the Creator is through study and intimate knowledge of every aspect of the creation (to the best of our ability). This is not a "Chabad" innovation. It is a central theme of all Torah teaching..

Comment: @RabbiKaii I believe the Hawking documentary can be purchased through Public Television on DVD. It's been a long time since I saw it, but I think it was perhaps in the 4th installment. There was an incredible animation illustrating the concept of continuous existence. Hawking had various opinions about the subject of G-d over his life. He tried to resist discussing it. But in the context of this continuous creation subject, he said asking about what is pushing existence to continue was like asking, "What is north of the north pole? It transcends existence."

Comment: Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan translated Zohar? I've seen and have Bahir and Sefer Yetzirah. I've never heard of him translating the Zohar. Are you sure?

Comment: @YaacovDeane I find Hawking's opinions about God and religion very cringe so I am trying to avoid it! I'd rather skip to the theory. If I must buy it and subject myself to that, so be it. Sounds worth it, thank you

Comment: @YaakovDeane Please reread my post. I said clearly it is not a Chabad idea. Although the Ba'al Hatanya may have had his own twist on it, but I haven't studied that particular topic (especially his writings) enough to comment. As a Litvak, I say creation is an expression of G-d's  will that we can comprehend up to a point. That includes everything from mud to people to angels to space dust to quarks and whatever they discover next.

Comment: @N.T. something that is constantly in motion cannot be called dead. Everything is composed of atoms and quarks, etc. which are constantly in motion, everything is being energized constantly by some force. A stone, which we may have previously called dead cannot be referred to as such anymore.

Comment: @YaacovDeane you maybe right about Rabbi kaplan's translation of the sefer yetzirah which I confused with the zohar, sorry

Comment: @larry909 Sure it can. You just made up a definition. Are the planets alive because gravity constantly keeps them in motion?

Comment: @N.T. alive in the sense that there is some discernable active force behind this existence. I'm specifically talking here about the atom. Planets are composed of mass which is made up of atoms, so that's where the conversation ultimately leads us.

Comment: @larry909 That is not what alive means. Find a different term for your concept.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE quantum physics is indeed ephemeral to a large degree

Comment: Finally, another guy who asks my kinds of questions.  Quantum Field Theory says that stuff is 'born' when the corresponding field is excited. So I feel that Dvar Havaya, which is sound, excites a certain field and makes the corresponding particle appear. For example, the entire Universe has an electromagnetic field. When G_d said, 'Let there be light', then those words created a vibration in the field which created light.

Comment: In QFT, everytime a certain vibration occurs in a field, the corresponding particle is created. If a vibration occurs in a 'candy' field, then that will lead to a candy popping out of nowhere. This was just a silly but to the point example.

Comment: You asked, 'Has there been any discussion about the possibility of quarks and atoms being a physical manifestation of this Dvar Havaya that is keeping the universe in existence?'.....The answer is yes, right here right now. QFT itself is a unique topic and IMHO we need to study and draw parallels to Torah creation. After all, the laws of Physics are what G_d uses to keep the Universe running.

Comment: Exactly as @shmosel said. There is nothing unique about these that differentiate them from anything else in creation. Everything physical is a manifestation of davar Hashem

Comment: @Dude I think this is different. Because you can physically see how everything is essentially made up of a few of the same particles, it's always in motion, and it's really all 99% empty space.

Answer (score 2):

The “Devar Havay’ah” is literally just what you said it is—G-D’s constant creation of the universe. The only reason the universe exists at any one moment is because G-D creates that moment and the things that happen in it. If G-D were to decide not to create the next moment, then the next moment would not exist. The universe doesn’t magically exist on its own. Everything exists only because G-D is currently, actively, and totally creating it, with every detail individually created every single individual instant.

Quarks and Atoms are just physical objects, constantly created exactly how and where they should be, over again at each individual moment. They are not the manifestation of anything in this context.

Comment: While your answer may be true, it does not address the specific question i.e. Has there been any discussion about the possibility of **quarks and atoms being a physical manifestation of this Dvar Havaya** that is keeping the universe in existence?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok could you explain your issue? "every detail individually created" sounds like it includes quarks and atoms to me? QwertyCTRL if no one has mentioned it yet: you really would benefit us all if you included sources in your answers

Comment: I edited the question and added the word "observable". >> Are quarks and atoms **an observable** physical manifestation of the Dvar Havaya that is keeping the universe in existence?